# Recurrence methode (Proof by induction)

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I want to demonstrate this equation by recurrence method

> $1-3+5-...+(-1)^n(2n+1)=(-1)^n(n+1)$

I did like that:

$$ n = 1 \implies 1 + (-1)^1(2\cdot1+1)=(-1)^1(1+1)$$

$$\implies 1-3 = -2$$

$$\implies -2 = -2$$

So the equation is true for $n=1$

Is what I did true or not, and how can I complete it for $n = n + 1$?

Comment: Hint : $$1-3=5-7=9-11=\cdots=-2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the inductive hypothesis you have:

$$ 1-3+5 \cdots (-1)^n(2n+1) + (-1)^{n+1}(2n+3) = (-1)^n(n+1) + (-1)^{n+1}(2n+3) = (-1)^{n+1}(2n+3 - n - 1) = (-1)^{n+1}(n+2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Please do not write $n=n+1.$

Let $S(n)= \sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^{j+1}(2j+1)$ and let $T(n)$ be the sentence $S(n)=(-1)^n(n+1).$ We prove that $T(0)$ is true (which is trivial). And we prove that $\forall n\;(T(n)\implies T(n+1)\;)$ as follows:

Note that $T(n+1)$ is  the sentence $S(n+1)=(-1)^{n+1}(n+2).$ Note that $S(n+1)=S(n)+(-1)^{n+1}(2n+3).$ $$\text {We have }\quad  T(n)\iff S(n)=(-1)^n(n+1)\implies$$ $$\implies S(n+1)=S(n)+(-1)^{n+1})2n+3)=$$ $$ =(-1)^n(n+1)+(-1)^{n+1}(2n+3)=$$ $$=(-1)^{n+1}(-(n+1)+(2n+3)\;)=$$ $$=(-1)^{n+1}(n+2)\implies$$ $$\implies S(n+1)=(-1)^{n+1}(n+2)\iff T(n+1).$$

Comment: thank you for your help